# Tightest proven upper bounds for the smallest prime of the for $an + b$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, it is known that there are infinitely many primes of the form $an + b$.

Denote $n(a, b)$ to be the smallest $n$ such that $an + b$ is prime.

$n(a, b) \leq \max(a, b)$ holds for $1 \leq a, b\leq 10000$.

> What is the tightest PROVEN upper bound for $n(a, b)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-studied problem, a key-word is "[Linnik's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem)."

Let us denote the least prime itself by $p(a,b)$, so $p(a,b) = b + n(a,b)a$. 
It is more common to express results in that way, and one can pass from on to the other easily.

Then Linnik proved $p(a,b) \le c a^L$ for some constants $c$ and $L$. 
Meanwhile the best constant $L$ for which this is known is $L=5$. 
At least for $L=5.5$ the constant $c$ is effectively computable (I am not sure an actual value was determined though).

It is conjecture that $L=2$ is true, and more precisely that $p(a,b) < a^2$.
Under the generalized Riemann hypothesis it is known that $p(a,b) \le (1+o(1)) \varphi(a)^2  \log(a)^2$.

For further details see the linked page.

Comment: But the catch is that the constant $c$ is not known, so there is no concrete proven upper bound.

Comment: I added a remark on $c$; for $L=5.5$ it could be computed, at least in principle.

Comment: But an upper bound for $c$, if $L=5.5$, was not given ?

Comment: I am not aware of a numerical value given by anybody, but  it could be extracted from the argument.

Comment: It is also astonishing that the bound is independent of $b$. Are there any restrictions for $b$ ? If b gets arbitary large and $a=1$, we would get $p(a,b)\le c$, so there would be a limit for the gap between primes, which is not the case.

Comment: None beyond the obvious one that it has to be coprime ot $a$. (And with the understanding that one searches in the full coset or $b \le a$. If one would allow $b$ large and consider just positive $n$ then of course the situation would change.)

Comment: So, Linnik's theorem is true for $b<a$ , but not for $b>a$ ?

Comment: Well, yes, the question is for primes in residue classes. If you consider the set $b + a \mathbb{Z}$ it does not matter how large the $b$ is. If you insist on $b + a \mathbb{N}$ then you'd need $b < a$ to get the same thing. The question for $b + a \mathbb{N}$ and no restriction on $b $ relative to $a$ is not cover by what I recall above (and does not seem particularly natural to me).

Comment: OK, thank you, maybe you can find out a concrete $c$ for $L=5.5$ :)